UUID input mask in Access - Input mask length limit
I'm creating an UUID field in an Access 2019 database and would like an input mask accordingly.
I have tried with the input mask >AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA in the input mask guide and the random UUID C92BF56D-89DF-41AB-B25F-536ED9606EE5 as example, but when trying to save the mask in the guide, I get the error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data."
By removing the last 6 characters in the mask I get rid of the error, so it seems to be a limit to the mask length. Obviously, this is not a solution as the saved data is no longer an UUID.
Is there a to increase the maximum mask length or some other way to achive a good UUID storage?

Found an answer while writing the question.
It seems the limitation is in the input mask guide, and not in the database itself. By manually entering the input mask >AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA;; directly in the field properties instead of using the guide it works.
